# Laravel 5 Eloquent objects and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am a beginner in Javascript and Jquery and I am trying to get data from the server, access them and display them without reloading the page with Ajax and Laravel 5.

So here is what I do:

My controller:

```
public function get_media_details(){
    $media_id       = $_POST['media_id'];
    $media_details = Media::find($media_id);

    print_r ($media_details);
}
```

My JS function:

```
function show_media_detail(media_id){

  $.ajax({
        url: "get_media_details",
        type:"POST",
        data: { media_id: media_id },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

            if (token) {
                  return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
            }
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log("No data returned");
        }
    });
  }
```

And the result of console.log(data):

```
    "App\Media Object
    (
    [table:protected] => media
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => feed_url
        )

     [connection:protected] => 
     [primaryKey:protected] => id
     [perPage:protected] => 15
     [incrementing] => 1
     [timestamps] => 1
     [attributes:protected] => Array
     (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => TechCrunch
        [description] => Breaking technology news and analysis.
        [link] => http://techcrunch.com/
        [feed_url] => http://techcrunch.com/feed/
        [thumbnail] => Rll0vnSkWk3bvTTWdthYzagXGnLHt9EHpU3Qe8XK
     )
etc...
```

But know I am trying to access specific value of this object, like for example, the name of my media.

I tried many things and searched a lot, but I keep failing miserably...
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
 print_r ($media_details);
```

to

```
 return $media_details;
```

in js file

```
  ... success:function(data){ 
  for (var x in data){
    console.log(data.description); // should output description 
  }
 ....
```

Comment: Works like a charm !! thank you so much :) I don't know why I used print_r.. that was stupid !

Comment: @Valentincognito most welcome, yeah it happens. I have done worst. But that is how you learn.